# Find number of missing numbers to complete consecutive array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a function that gives you the number of numbers need to complete a consecutive array. For example if we have the array [3,5,7] the function should return 2 (i.e. 4,6). I have come up with the code below but it gives me the following error? Any ideas why? Thanks!

```
    def consecutive(*arr)

      sorted = arr.sort
      current_count = 0

      sorted.each_index do |i| 
        next if i == sorted.length
        difference = arr[i+1] - arr[i] - 1
        current_count += difference
      end 

      current_count
    end
```

And this is the error:

```
   undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
   (repl):9:in `block in Consecutive'
   (repl):6:in `each_index'
   (repl):6:in `Consecutive'
   (repl):16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: 1. `i == sorted.length` will never be true. 2. When `i  == sorted.size - 1`, `arr[i+1] #=> nil`, so `arr[i+1] - arr[i]`, which is shorthand for `arr[i+1].-(arr[i])`, evaluates to `nil.-(arr[i])`, but `nil` has no method `:-`; i.e., `NilClass` has no instance method `:-`. 3. Method (and variable) names are to be "snake_case", which begins with a lower case letter. `Consecutive`, since it begins with a capital letter, is a constant.

Comment: wow do many mistakes in such a small piece of code. Thank you @CarySwoveland

Comment: Thanks for the ✅, but in future consider waiting longer before making a selection. Others may be still working on answers and an early selection may discourage other answers. More than once I've seen an answer posted after the selection has been made that is a better answer or shows the selected answer to be incorrect. There's no rush to award the greenie. Many here wait at the least a couple of hours--often longer--before doing so.

Comment: I will in the future - still learning. Thank you Cary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `arr` is your array, you can do this:

```
arr = [3,1,5,7,8]

f,l = arr.minmax
  #=> [1, 8] 
l-f+1 - arr.size
  #=> 3
```

Comment: You could do this in one line, and avoid the creation of the local variables `f` and `l`, but is would be less readable: `arr.minmax.reverse.reduce(:-) + 1 - arr.size` #=> 3.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i + 1]` is going to be nil on your final pass through `each_index`. You can use `each_cons(2)` instead and have it deal with the indices for you:

```
def Consecutive(arr)
  sorted = arr.sort
  current_count = 0

  sorted.each_cons(2) do |a, b|
    difference = b - a - 1
    current_count += difference
  end 

  current_count
end

Consecutive([3,5,7])
 => 2
```